# Binding differences between .Net Core 1.1 from .Net 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am migrating services from MVC .NET 4.6.1 to .NET Core 1.1.  I notice that the binding is different when trying to pass an object to an action. In 4.6.1, a json property with a null value maps to an integer value of 0. However, in .NET Core the overall object is nullified.

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost("api/[controller]")]
public IActionResult PostGraph([FromBody] Graph graph)
```

.NET Object:

```
public class Graph{
    public string Name {get; set}
    public int GraphId {get; set;}
}
```

This binds to the action in both .NET 4.6.1 and .NET Core 1.1:

```
{ "GraphId":12, "Name":"test" }
```

This only binds to the action in .NET 4.6.1, the object is null in .NET Core 1.1:

```
{ "GraphId":null, "Name":"test" }
```

I feel like I'm missing a configuration setting or maybe using the wrong json parser. Is there an elegant way to map integers to 0 that come from null json values?

Comment: Do you port from **ASP.NET Core** with .NET 4.6.1 to ASP.NET Core with .NET Core 1.1 or from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core? ASP.NET Core should behave same on .NET 4.6.1 and .NET Core

Comment: Sorry I mixed it up some. I'm moving from VS 2015 .NET WebApi app with Framework 4.6.1 to VS2017 with MVC app using .NETCoreApp 1.1. I actually have figured it out.  I looked for an answer for a while, and directly after posting this I found something.  The fix was in the Startup.cs file I added JsonOptions to the services object.

Comment: You keep mixing .NET with ASP.NET. ASP.NET is a webstack, .NET is a runtime and it's still not clear if you are migrating from ASP.NET MVC 5 (the last ASP.NET before ASP.NET **Core** came out)  or if you are just switching runtimes on ASP.NET Core. Both can be created with VS2015 and VS2017!